# virtualenv is not recognizing installed packages in one machine despite working on another machine

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I have an internet-connected machine, computer "A" which is running Windows, in which I'm building a `virtualenv` (Python 3.7.2, venv 1.16.4) for a non-internet connected device, computer "B" which is also Windows. The `virtualenv` exists on USB device. Copying the project from the USB to the host machine makes no difference (I have tested.).

The `virtualenv` works on "A", **no problem at all**, but on "B", ***even after activating*** the `venv`, it ***doesn't*** recognize `pip` or `numpy`, and so I cannot "`pip`" anything, and cannot do `import numpy` in IDLE... although IDLE does run. (Again, `Numpy` is definitely installed into the `virtualenv`.)

```
cd <env project folder>
.\env\Scripts\activate # venv activates
py # launch IDLE
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

And yet I see:

```
cd /env/Lib/site-packages/
ls 

    Directory: C:<path/to/site-packages>

Mode                  LastWriteTime        Length  Name
----                  -------------        ------  ----
d-----               <today's date>                numpy
d-----               <today's date>                numpy-1.16.4.dist-info
```

So it should work.

***Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?***

Let me know if you need more specific details.

Comment: Do you get the path to the venv when you type in `which py`?

Comment: `where py` (Windows) gives no results, and simply returns another line of my current directory.

Comment: It should be a location within the venv. What happens when you do 'where py' on machine A?

Comment: small correction to myself, `get-command` is the Windows equivalent to `which`. In answer to your comment, `get-command` returns the path to the globally installed Python.

Comment: It should return the path to the venv python. Otherwise, there's something wrong with how the environment was set up.

Answer (score 0):

Python was not packaged into the `virtualenv`. Machine "A" was using one global interpreter, with many global packages already installed, while "B" was using its own global interpreter, with no packages installed.

This was fixed by setting up the virtualenv with a new parameter.

```
python -m virtualenv -p python env
```